# how to reduce timeout b/w first and second chord key in vscode keybinding?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to reduce timeout b/w first and second chord key in vscode keybinding?

in other words, I want to reduce the waiting period to listen to the second chord key (cmd+enter):

[image]